# Javascript - local scope objects not accessible from nested function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, local-variables

I am trying to have a function grab an object from a php file on another page. I'm using the jQuery ajax function to to do the json grab, which is working correctly. The issue is when I try to return that object from the function.

The first time I log the object (from within the success function) it is correct in the console, but the returned object from the function getGantt() logs as "undefined".

How do I get this object out of the function?

My code:

```
    function getGantt(requestNumber){
        var ganttObject;
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "get_gantt.php",
               data: {request_number: requestNumber},
               success: function(returnValue){
                     ganttObject = $.parseJSON(returnValue);
                    console.log(ganttObject); //this logs a correct object in the console

                }
        });
        return ganttObject;
    }

    $(function(){ //document ready function

        var requestNumber = $('#request_number').text();

        var ganttObject = getGantt(requestNumber);
        console.log(ganttObject); //this logs "undefined"

    }); //end document ready function
```

Comment: you are returning a variable before ajax callback gets to set the ganttObject.

Comment: AJAX is runs asynchronously, your `getGantt` function doesn't get the value until after the AJAX process is complete, which is after the return has happened.  You need to restructure your programming to (a) use `returnValue` in the success function (b) store returnValue in a global/object variable that's accessible later (causes issues with the triggering/waiting process required)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers everyone; stackoverflow is insanely fast. Three good answers in under 10 minutes!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The A in Ajax is an important part of the acronym. Asynchronous JavaScript and XML is asynchronous.

`$.ajax({success:someFunction})` means *Make an HTTP request and when the response arrives, run `someFunction`*

`return ganttObject` runs **before** the response arrives.

You should do anything you want to do with the data **inside** `someFunction` and not try to return data to the calling function.

Comment: LOL love the A in Ajax is an important part of the acronym...going to use that next time.

Comment: I should probably add that the X isn't important ;)

Comment: Thanks, I had completely forgotten about ajax being taken out of normal flow. This answers my question completely.

Comment: Dorward - not just not important, but misleading :)

Comment: The A is important, but the X is not, now that most people use JSON instead of XML

Answer (score 1):

The A in AJAX stands for asynchronous. So the call immediately returns and as soon as it finishes, the success callback is called.

So, simply change your code to use a callback:

```
function getGantt(requestNumber, callback) {
    var ganttObject;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "get_gantt.php",
        data: {request_number: requestNumber},
        success: function(returnValue){
            callback(returnValue);
        }
    });
}

$(function() {

    var requestNumber = $('#request_number').text();

    var ganttObject = getGantt(requestNumber, function(ganttObject) {
        console.log(ganttObject);
    });

});
```

Btw, I've also removed this parseJSON stuff - setting dataType to json does the job and is less dirty.

Answer (score 0):

I know why it's not returning it at least. The ganttObject may be in the same scope, but the success function is ultimately running in the readyState callback from the XMLHTTP object, so it's on a different thread than the getGantt function. Can you make the  $(function(){... code apart of your success function?