# Returning values

Tags: jquery, ajax, return-value

I'm using this function on a jquery script:

```
    function recogerEventos(id) {
    var respuesta = $.ajax( {
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'eventos.php',
        data: 'cmd=recoge&id='+id,
        success: function(data) {
        //alert(data);

            return data;
        },
        error : function () {
            return false;
        }
    }).responseText;
    //alert("asdfksjfhajk"+respuesta);
    return respuesta;
}
```

If I uncomment the alert(data) it shows the return string value, but when I uncomment the alert("asdffksd...") it shows only the random letters and no more, I need to send this 'respuesta' value to get string in other document.

If someone know how to get it, please, explain me, i'm desperate

Thanks to all, Carlos

Comment: Duplicate of [Javascript - local scope objects not accessible from nested function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891491/javascript-local-scope-objects-not-accessible-from-nested-function) (The only difference is that the alert stops the return statement form being hit until OK is clicked, and that gives the response time to come back. The solution is still the same though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is to set the `async` option to false, which allows you to return the data directly from the call to `ajax`. eg.

```
var respuesta = $.ajax({
    url:   'eventos.php',
    async: false,
    ...
}).responseText;
```

The downside to this approach is that it will block the browser whilst it waits for the request to complete.

Answer (score 2):

You should provide a callback function to the recogerEventos function. So you can call that when the ajax request is finished.

```
function recogerEventos(id, callback, errorcallback) {
    var respuesta = $.ajax( {
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'eventos.php',
        data: 'cmd=recoge&id='+id,
        success: callback,
        error : errorcallback
    });
}
```

Or you can do the update in the RecogerEventos directly:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $("#results").append(html);
  }
```

Comment: uhm, the recogerEventos, sends a string which is get by another function to write the text on a loaded javascript file

Comment: See the update, callback should be the function that writes the text on a loaded javascript file (whatever that means?)